# How to make div editable which is created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, onclick

I want to make **div** editable which is created **dynamically**. Which is also **draggable** div .

This is what I tried

```
1)$("#divid").attr('contentEditable','true');

2)$("#divid").live("click",function(){
     $(this).click('contentEditable',true);
  });

3)$("#divid").click('contentEditable',true);
```

but none of the above working. 
Any idea how to make it working!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: once try `on` instead of `live`

Comment: @Mr_Green I tried but not working

Comment: Ok I thought it might work as `live` is deprecated in newer versions of jquery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are having a dynamically created div use `.on()` handler for it and `.prop()`:

```
  $(document).on("click", "#divid", function(){
     $(this).prop('contentEditable',true);
  });
```

find out in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SEvDe/

Comment: @AleksandrM I thought the same but still not working , can this is because of this div is a draggable too?

Comment: @sandip linked a fiddle in the answer.

Comment: @Jai: the result of your fiddle is not content editable in chrome. it appears an element can't be both draggable and content editable in chrome, regardless of how it is created.

Comment: @Jai: No repro in v23 on windows. The div is draggable, but not editable.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Will you please reexplain above comment

Comment: @sandip: my last comment was in response to to Jai's last comment. I'm describing the behavior of Jai's fiddle in chrome 23 on windows.

Comment: @jai,@AleksandrM,@ameyarote,@DavidHedlund Thank you So much for your answers - 
I just added <h3> element divid.innerHTML="<h3 onClick='this.contentEditable=true;'>hello!</h3>";
And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VV7BW/1/)

```
$("#test").get(0).contentEditable = "true";
$("#test1").attr('contentEditable',true);
```

It works as a charm.

with **javascript** u could have tried this

```
document.getElementById("contentDiv").contentEditable = "true";
```

Comment: not working ! I think you guies forgetting wht I said this div is a draggable